# Make a #-tag javascript link word for non javascript

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, hashtag

Using the following tutorial I want my website to use AJAX to load the content (but also want to be able to use the back button etc. etc):
http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp

Ofcourse if someone has javascript disabled the website should also work (without Ajax).

The problem however comes when a javascript enabled user sends a link to a non javascript enabled user. Because javascript is disabled it will not handle the #-tag correctly and will just go to the homepage (so linking directly to pages from a javascript user to non-javascript user is impossible). Is there a way to resolve this issue (preferably php or htacces).

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but I generally just ignore the effects for the once-in-a-blue-moon user that has javascript disabled. Don't even worry about them. Thinking about users with javascript disabled is as pointless as optimizing your code for Netscape Navigator.

Comment: @stereofrog, Yes, that is why you write semantic mark-up. That and for text-based browers and accessibility.

Comment: It's still pointless to worry about actual people using web browsers without javascript. (The exception of course being mobile, but generally you change a lot for mobile).

Comment: I built the frontend of a site for a large corporate client. Later they asked if I could make it work on the older Blackberry devices they used. Before Blackberry went Webkit, their browser was a disaster when it came to js. Avoiding executing js for those devices got me 95% of the way there. Coding the site to work without JS from the outset really paid off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 gives us methods to alter the URL without refreshing the page https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries

This means you can update something without a page refresh but still give the user a url they can bookmark or send to someone else. These urls will work without JavaScript, as long as you have pages at those locations or are catching them with mod_rewrite or similar.

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js is a great little pollyfill which will use the HTML5 history stuff if the browser supports it, otherwise (Internet Explorer) it changes the hash of the url.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, three steps:

- code your "a" tags just normal: `<a href='about'>About us</a>`
- in your javascript code, intercept all `click` events on `<a>` tags and navigate to `#` + `this.href`. So when they click the above url, you navigate to `site.com/#about` instead of `site.com/about`
- in your javascript code, have a timer function that reads the hash value form the current location and loads a corresponding url (with # removed) via ajax

Since you code your html just as usual, the site remains fully accessible for non-js users, and, more important, for search engines' bots.

In response to the comments I can suggest the following:

- redirect your home page via javascript from just `site.com` to `site.com/js/`
- when `<a href='about'>` is clicked, navigate to `site.com/js/#about`
- on the "js" page, have something like `<a id=about href="/about">click here</a>` for non-js users

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of js-enabled users sending links to no-js users

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you described is already what he's doing (actually I'm 100% sure since I'm sitting next to him), the problem is redirecting a non-js user to the right page if he goes to `site.com/#about` (if it's possible).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just build your application normally and then add the AJAX on top, rather than going the other way round and causing more work for yourself?

Ask yourself, why do you need AJAX page transitions? Does your app actually *need* them, or is it just because you've seen it on another site, like Twitter?

Comment: He is saying in his question that the website should also work without AJAX, it's an extra functionality he's trying to add and he's asking how to make it work.

Comment: It read to me he was creating a website and wanting this functionality from the get-go, but in my opinion he's going about it the wrong way and concentrating too much on having the hash character present in URLs. URLs with hashes are, by definition, fragment identifiers; that is, for **fragments** of a page, not individual pages themselves.